# How to link a static HTML file not generated by Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I use docusaurus and I want include static html page generated by an other part of my environement.

Online: https://stackblitz.com/github/facebook/docusaurus/tree/starter

**/src/pages/helloReact.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '@theme/Layout';

function Hello() {
  return (
    <Layout title="Hello">
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          height: '50vh',
          fontSize: '20px',
        }}>
        <p>
          Edit <code>pages/helloReact.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Hello;
```

but HTML code is not in other HTML file (static/foo/bar/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

On Discord Server (thanks guys!) they suggested me to use Escaping from SPA redirects: https://docusaurus.io/docs/advanced/routing#escaping-from-spa-redirects

Working examples to link sub_folder/my_file.html:

1. in a \docs MD file

`[My File](pathname:///sub_folder/my_file.html)`

2. in the upper bar (docusausur.config.ts)

```
{
    to: 'pathname:///sub_folder/my_file.html', 
    label: 'My File', 
    position: 'right',
},
```

It works, but the link is opened in a new tab, without the Docusaurus frame.